# CSS Centering and reducing height of a div container

Tags: css, wordpress

Here I am working within the edit the CSS of a wordpress plugin. The purpose of the plugin is to add a fixed position box at the top of the website where the user can read and click on a link as you scroll the site.

[image: header]

The issues that I am having is that I want the box to match the main sites "dark blue" band's height. Changing the CSS and using like height: 80%; isn't quite working here.

I also wanted to center the light blue box to the center ( I am also going to change the width of it to just fit the content that it holds).

This is my first time applying CSS, so I'm not sure what I'm doing here. I am not able to edit the code directly, just put in CSS "options".

My code is:

```
<div id="topbar" style="position:fixed; top: 20; padding:0; margin:0; width:  50%; z-index: 99999;opacity:.7; height:80%;"  >
<div id="wptbheadline1" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; vertical-align:middle; family:georgia; padding-right:10px; padding-left:10px;"   >Check out our Twitter
  <a style=""   HTML Option B</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to add a unit here: `top: 20;`

Comment: Do you know the height of the "dark blue" band?

Comment: Paulie, when I expect the element in the browser it tells me that its 960x28 so I'm guessing that's 28px.

I tried adding height: 28px; but nothing changes

I tried adding top: 20; on the wptbheadline1's style line, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking to achieve; See below.

```css
#topbar {background: orange;color:#fff;} /* ignore this css */
```

```html
<div id="topbar" style="position:fixed; top: 20; padding:7px 0; margin:0; width:  50%; z-index: 99999;opacity:.7; transform: translateX(50%); text-align: center"  >
<div id="wptbheadline1" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; vertical-align:middle; family:georgia; padding-right:10px; padding-left:10px;"   >Check out our Twitter
  <a style=""   HTML Option B</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Adjust the `padding :7px 0;` to fit the height.

Comment: This transform worked for me. I'm not going to use the padding change since I want the bar to hug the top, but both options still result in the bar overextending.